# How to launch an actvity from a dialog in a xml preference?

Tags: java, android, xml

OK, I have a settings activity that is filled from a preferences.xml with `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);`, there is a dialog preference:

```
<com.android.maxr1998.cleanit.DialogPreference
    android:title="@string/pref_dev"
    android:key="dev"
    android:dialogIcon="@drawable/alerts_and_states_warning"
    android:dialogLayout="@layout/dev_dialog"
    android:positiveButtonText="@android:string/yes"
    android:negativeButtonText="@android:string/cancel"/>
```

Now, when I click Yes, I want another Activity to be launched...

This is my DialogPreference.class

```
package com.android.maxr1998.cleanit;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class DialogPreference extends android.preference.DialogPreference {

    public DialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    public interface ClickListener {
        public void onPositiveBtnClicked(...?);
    }

}
```

What do I specifically have to put at "...?" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it this way:

- Used normal preference
- Applied onclicklistener on Preference in Activity
- Launch AlertDialog from it
- Positive button click in alertdialog fires up activity

Answer (score 2):

Write a Interface for the DialogPreference. Implement that in your activity. In positive click event callback.

```
class DialogPreference extends ... {
   public interface ClickListener {
      public void onPositiveBtnClicked(...);
   }
   public void setListener(ClickListener l) {
      mClickListener = l;
   }
   @Override
   onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      if(which == DialogInterface .BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
         mClickListener.onPositiveBtnClicked(...)
      }
   }
}
```